# Avoid repeating WHERE conditions in subqueries

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, subquery, inner-join

I have an SQL query along the lines of:

```sql
SELECT * FROM a 
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT date, MAX(z) FROM a
        WHERE a.x = "foo" AND a.y IN (1, 2, 3)
        GROUP BY z
    ) b
    ON a.date = b.date
WHERE a.x = "foo" AND a.y IN (1, 2, 3)
```

My question is, is it a code smell to have this duplicate WHERE condition? Maybe the answer depends on the particular context but I'm hoping for an "in general" answer, or some pointers in how I would go about making it better.

Comment: This doesn’t even compile: You can’t group by an expression you are aggregating. I don’t know what you’re trying to do, by `group by date` would at least compile. Please correct your query to be syntactically correct

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and the expected result? There's probably a much simple solution than your query.

Comment: @Bohemian, can you explain? It compiles here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xevfg5qvjeuVDy57uMV69E/1.

I copied/pasted directly into my question.

Comment: @TheImpaler, this isn't for a specific example. I'm asking about whether repeated WHERE conditions are "OK" or not or if there is always a better way. If you think it depends on the particular example than please say so.

Comment: @jarthur repeated WHERE conditions are fine if they solve the problem and there is no better alternative. What is not clear in your case is what you want to do. If you clarify your requirement then maybe we can propose a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This subquery:

```
SELECT date, MAX(z) FROM a
WHERE a.x = "foo" AND a.y IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY z
```

is allowed in SQLite, but it would be invalid in most other databases, because although you `GROUP BY z` you are also aggregating on `z` and you are selecting the non aggregated column `date`.

Anyway, what this query does is filter the table under the conditions of the `WHERE` clause and then return 1 row for each distinct `z` (since `MAX(z)` is actually equal to `z` in its own group) with an arbitrary value for `date`.

Then you join the table with the this subquery on the arbitrary dates that the subquery returns. This is all very unclear about what you have in mind as the expected output.

But, if your concern is about the repeating conditions, then I should say that it's always better if you can avoid them.

In your case there is the solution of a `CTE`, because in your main query and your subquery, you are doing the same filtering, so you are interested only in the rows for which these conditions are satisfied:

```
a.x = "foo" AND a.y IN (1, 2, 3)
```

So you can get the same results like this:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT * FROM a 
  WHERE a.x = "foo" AND a.y IN (1, 2, 3)
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte c
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT date, MAX(z) FROM cte
  GROUP BY z
) b ON b.date = c.date
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=00d38614f036cd77b4c7f6a17a337571).

Comment: "But, if your concern is about the repeating conditions, then I should say that it's always better if you can avoid them." This was really what I was looking for. I should have emphasised more that the example query in the OP was not really relevant (my actual query does not have the `GROUP BY` aggregation issue -- that was an oversight on my behalf). Also thank you for posting an alternative solution, this is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions.  If you want the maximum date per z:

```
SELECT a.*,
       MAX(z) OVER (PARTITION BY date)
FROM a 
WHERE a.x = "foo" AND a.y IN (1, 2, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the maximum `z` for the `date`, then you *do* need both `where` clauses, because without its `where` clause the subquery would return the max `z` for *any* row for the `date`, not the max `z` for the rows you are querying.

Your query has a minor bug through: the subquery should use `GROUP BY date` rather than `GROUP BY z`:

```
SELECT * FROM a 
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT date, MAX(z) FROM a
    WHERE a.x = "foo" AND a.y IN (1, 2, 3)
    GROUP BY date
) b
ON a.date = b.date
WHERE a.x = "foo" AND a.y IN (1, 2, 3)
```